# Maximum Cy extents for a PowerPoint slide

Tags: powerpoint

For a given PowerPoint 2003 slide, what is the maximum Cy extents for it?  I looked in the xml structure and was unable to find such number.  Google wasn't helpful either.

Thanks.

Comment: PowerPoint 2003 doesn't use XML. Are you referring to PowerPoint 2007 instead?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it is the maximum value that you are looking for but the value that corresponds with the bottom of the current slide. I don't know this off the top of my head but you could find out with trial and error.

The maximum value would equate to somewhere way out in the middle of nowhere, lost in space.
Don't forget to convert values to EMU.